# How ldd command know which virtual address shared library is loaded?

Tags: linux, compilation, linker, dynamic-linking

typical `ldd something` usually output `shared_library_name => shared_library_path : virtual addr`

As far as I understanding dynamic linking correctly, the virtual address that any shared library is loaded at is determined at runtime. so how can `ldd` possibly know where the shared library is loaded ? Does is by emulate a dynamic linking process or what ?

Comment: Did you read the [ldd manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html)? "*ldd invokes the standard dynamic linker. This causes the dynamic linker to inspect the
       program's dynamic dependencies, and find (according to the rules
       described in ld.so(8)) and load the objects that satisfy those
       dependencies*"

Comment: thanks for your reply, would it be possible to get different result every time I execute `ldd something` ? since address is determined at runtime ?

Comment: Yes it is possible